# Trying to make a HASEL actuator

Tags: high-voltage, dielectric

I was told that if I apply high voltage to a zip lock bag filled with baby oil with tin foil paper on the end it'd make it contract and act as a HASEL actuator.

I'm afraid of measuring the exact voltage if the device because I don't want to break my voltmeter but I read it's atleast 40 kV, and that is above what is required for a HASEL actuator I think.

I'd like help and clues as to what I should do next.

Here is the link with the experiment: [The attempt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15BkthWas2S2ozun5DBLA1t3rCKavYCXE/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Show a diagram please.

Comment: I don't have the diagram... It's a ziplock bag with baby oil, tinfoil paper connected via gator clips and I don't know the inner circuit of the high voltage device... It's powered by a 3.3v-5v power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply laying loose sheets of tin foil over a plastic bag will likely not achieve much of an effect. Many of the simple internet examples depicting this effect seem to be a bit exaggerated just to show the concept.

According to one reference you can try using conductive paint to create sort of a parallel plate capacitor on opposing sides of a flexible polymer bag containing a dielectric fluid. Energizing the plates with an opposing high voltage should causes the plates to attract each other and this displaces some of the fluid. If properly shaped the bag may distort from the displaced fluid and this can mimic the action of a natural muscle.

Having the bag flat and the conductive plates fairly close together will likely allow the effect to be seen more easily.

Here is a paper explaining the HASEL actuator concept with some actual examples:
https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2102/2102.13039.pdf

While the effect is simple electrostatics you could get a similar effect (with low voltage) using a flat steel plate laying over a bag of fluid with an electromagnet placed under it.

Comment: I wanted to up vote but don't have enough points. Thank you...

Comment: @peteblank - No problem. Also, be extremely careful working with high voltages.  This device creates a high voltage capacitor that can be even more dangerous. Try to find some very high value resistors (50M ohm or more), and place these across the power supply and across the opposing actuator plates. The resistor helps bleed off high voltage from the supply when shut down and from the plates after disconnecting the leads. Another high voltage practice is to work with one hand behind your back when power is live, this reduces the chance of ever getting your hands across the high voltage points.